# Why does the second view controller didn´t appear after loading the entry view, but by clicking on a button, he does?

Tags: ios, viewdidload

Why does the second view controller didn´t appear after loading the entry view, but by clicking on a button, he does?

Here is my code:

```
@IBAction func Pressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    var firstName = FirstName.text;
    var lastName = LastName.text;
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard;
    defaults.set(firstName, forKey: "FN");
    defaults.set(lastName, forKey: "LN");
    loadNextView()
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.FirstName.text = "TESTAUSGABE";
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard;
    var fn = defaults.object(forKey: "FN")
    var ln = defaults.object(forKey: "LN")
    if(fn==nil){
        self.FirstName.placeholder="Nicht angegeben"
    }
    else {
        self.FirstName.text = fn as? String
        loadNextView()
    }
    if(ln==nil){
        self.LastName.placeholder="Nicht angegeben"
    }
    else{
        self.LastName.text = ln as? String
        self.Pressed(self.SaveButton);
    }
}
func loadNextView(){
    let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name:"Main", bundle:nil);
    let newViewControler = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "View2") as UIViewController
    self.present(newViewControler, animated: true, completion: nil) 
}
```

I want to check the preferences and if they are already set then it should appear automatically another view.
Or is there another method I didn't know?

Comment: Try to call loadNextView() from viewDidAppear/viewWillAppear instead of viewDidLoad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prsenting VCs doesn't work inside `viewDidLoad` as the view hierarchy is not yet complete , You can try to implement `viewDidAppear` or `viewWillAppear`

```
var runOnce  = true
```

//

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated:Bool){ 
  super.viewDidAppear(animated)
   if runOnce {
      loadNextView() // here read default value 
      runOnce = false 
  }
}
```